# Количество нейронов в последнем слое

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Есть [датасет фруктов](https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits). Простая нейронная сеть:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
import sklearn as sk
# we'll use keras for our neural-network
# using tenserflow backend
# you can also try tensorflow-gpu
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
# fast imports
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout


# versions
print("Keras version: " + keras.__version__)
print("Tensorflow version: " + tf.__version__)

# downoloading data
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\x\\fruits-360\\Training',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='binary')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\x\\fruits-360\\Validation',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:\\Users\\x\\fruits-360\\Validation',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(100, 100, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# size of mini-data
batch_size = 64
# train data
train_data = 28736
# validation data
valid_data = 9673
# test data
test_data = 9673

# generate our neural-network
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_data // batch_size,
    epochs=7,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=valid_data // batch_size)

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_data // batch_size)
print("Аккуратность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Точность этой нейронной сети очень маленькая.
При изменении предпоследнего `Dense()`, точность этой сети может кардинально измениться.

Как подобрать количество нейронов в этом  `Dense()`, чтобы повысить точность программы?

Comment: Я только начинаю это изучать , из-за этого если вопрос не понятен или мало информации спросите в коментариях .

Comment: Есть формулы по вычислению нейронов на последнем слое  , но я не знаю как их применить . Как можно понять, сколько входных и выходных нейронов в свёрточной нейронной сети?

Comment: Я знаю что есть много похожих вопросов , но на них также нету ответов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас целый ряд логических ошибок:

1. для мультиклассовой классификации (вы же определяете вид/тип фрукта, а не факт изображен ли на картинке фрукт или "не фрукт") на последнем слое надо использовать число нейронов соответствующее числу классов (разных видов фруктов, т.е. 60) и использовать `activation='softmax'` вместо `activation='sigmoid'`
2. В качестве функции потери (loss function) опять же надо использовать `'categorical_crossentropy'` вместо `'binary_crossentropy'`, которая используется только для бинарной классификации.
3. По той же причине надо поменять во всех вызовах `datagen.flow_from_directory(..., class_mode='binary')` на `datagen.flow_from_directory(..., class_mode='categorical')`

Вот подправленный код целиком:

```
# imports
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sc
import sklearn as sk
# we'll use keras for our neural-network
# using tenserflow backend
# you can also try tensorflow-gpu
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
# fast imports
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

input_shape = (100, 100, 3)

# versions
print("Keras version: " + keras.__version__)
print("Tensorflow version: " + tf.__version__)

# downoloading data
path = Path(r"/path/to/data/fruits-360")
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path / 'Training',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path / 'Validation',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path / 'Validation',
    target_size=(100, 100),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical')

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Model summary')
print(model.summary())

# size of mini-data
batch_size = 64
# train data
train_data = 28736
# validation data
valid_data = 9673
# test data
test_data = 9673

# generate our neural-network
model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_data // batch_size,
    epochs=7,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=valid_data // batch_size)

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, test_data // batch_size)
print("Аккуратность на тестовых данных: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Вывод программы:

```
Keras version: 2.1.5
Tensorflow version: 1.8.0
Found 28736 images belonging to 60 classes.
Found 9673 images belonging to 60 classes.
Found 9673 images belonging to 60 classes.
Model summary
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 98, 98, 32)        896
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPooling (None, 49, 49, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 47, 47, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 23, 23, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 23, 23, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)           (None, 21, 21, 32)        18464
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 10, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)          (None, 3200)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 64)                204864
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 60)                3900
=================================================================
Total params: 246,620
Trainable params: 246,620
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/7
449/449 [==============================] - 785s 2s/step - loss: 2.0230 - acc: 0.4298 - val_loss: 0.4334 - val_acc: 0.8779
Epoch 2/7
449/449 [==============================] - 781s 2s/step - loss: 0.6728 - acc: 0.7705 - val_loss: 0.2270 - val_acc: 0.9296
Epoch 3/7
449/449 [==============================] - 762s 2s/step - loss: 0.4570 - acc: 0.8390 - val_loss: 0.1831 - val_acc: 0.9362
Epoch 4/7
320/449 [====================>.........] - ETA: 3:16 - loss: 0.3632 - acc: 0.8692
```

PS обучение еще не окончено...

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Я новичок , из-за этого достаточно много совершаю ошибок(.

Comment: @True-hacker, всегда рад помочь :)