# Как поставить определенный аутпут в нейронной сети, в зависимости от класса?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

У меня есть датасет на 24к картинок для каждой картинки есть файлик с описанием, там есть информацией, к какому классу относится изображение(всего 19 классов). Мне нужно обучить модель, я хочу в зависимости от класса ставить лейбл(ожидаемое значение на выходе) от 0 до 1, включая промежуточные значения, например класс А = 0.33 на выходе НС, класс Б = 0.63 и тд. Как мне это реализовать на тензорфлоу или керасе. Гуглинг не помог. Спасибо.

Comment: [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829438/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5/829833#829833)

Comment: Этот вариант мне не подходит, потому что у меня 19 классов - это 19 состояний одного объекта, я хочу научить сеть определять к какому состоянию она принадлежит, состояние отображается в значении 0-1(включая значения между 0 и 1)

Comment: именно это данная модель и делает - возвращает матрицу с 60-ю стоолбцами с вероятностями принадлежности к каждому классу (фрукты)

Comment: Нет, мне нужно, чтобы возвращалась одна вероятность, меня не нужно пытаться переубедить, у меня такая идея, я просто спросил, как это можно реализовать

Comment: и что эта одна вероятность должна показывать? Это уже будет не вероятность а метка. Просто вместо "яблоко" вы получите на выходе `0.33`, но `0.33` - не будет иметь ничего общего с вероятностью...

Comment: Есть датасет родинок,  у одних вероятность, чтобы они переродятся в раковые допустим 35%, у других 50%, другие уже раковые - 100%, другие вообще никогда не переродятся - 0%, я хочу научить сеть выдавать опасность перерождения в рак родинки

Comment: А что находится в "файлике с описанием" в обучающей выборке?

Comment: Диагнозы, еще возраст и пол, но их я думаю опустить. С помощью гуглинга я определил вероятность перерождения в рак кажого диагноза

Comment: Так что, вы сможете помочь, рассказав, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Судя по описанию это задача регрессии а не классификации. Ищите в сети примеры моделей регрессии по изображениям