# Как организовать память при обучении сверточной нейросети?

Tags: python-3.x, память, нейронные-сети

Пытаюсь написать сверточную нейронную сеть с помощью Python 3.6 + TensorFlow + tflearn по аналогии с [этим](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py#L15) примером.
Насколько я понимаю, строчка, начинающая обучение сети,

```
model.fit({'input': X}, {'target': Y}, n_epoch=20,
           validation_set=({'input': testX}, {'target': testY}),
           snapshot_step=100, show_metric=True, run_id='convnet_mnist')
```

требует полностью загруженный в память массив. Однако я использую большое количество изображений для обучения (28000), и полная их загрузка в массив гарантированно забивает всю память и вызывает ошибку.

Я использую следующий код для загрузки изображений:

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

X = np.zeros(shape=(28000,140,170,3))    
i=0
for name in glob('*.png'):
    X[i] = cv2.imread(name)                
    i+=1
```

Можно ли каким-либо способом организовать хранение/постепенную подгрузку массива по частям так, чтобы это не вызывало ошибку?

Comment: я не работал с `tflearn`, но и в `keras` и в `tensorflow` есть возможность использовать `model.fit_generator(...)`. [Вот пример на Keras](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829833/211923)