# Ошибка Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (500, 500, 1) but got array with shape (500, 500, 3)

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

При вызове метода обучения модели в Keras выходит ошибка:

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (178, 500, 500, 3)
```

Вот сам код:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.utils import np_utils
from Images.LoadImage import LoadImage



np.random.seed(42)

X_train = []
Y_train = []

LoadImage.upload_all_images_with_name_from(directory = r"D:\Documents\Desktop\noise1", array = X_train, image_sizes = (500, 500))
LoadImage.upload_all_images_with_name_from(directory = r"D:\Documents\Desktop\noise", array = Y_train, files_common_name = "img_y", image_sizes = (500, 500))
X_train = np.array(X_train)
Y_train = np.array(Y_train)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(800, input_shape=(500, 500, 3,)))
model.add(Dense(800))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss = 'mse',
    metrics = ['mae']
    )

model.fit(
    x = X_train,
    y = Y_train,
    batch_size = 3,
    epochs = 100
    )

LoadImage.save_model_json(model, "D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RegressionTraining\RegressionTraining\model.json")
model.save_weights("D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RegressionTraining\RegressionTraining\model_weights.h5")

a = load_img("D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RegressionTraining\img0.png", target_size=(500, 500))
b = load_img("D:\Documents\Desktop\Python\RegressionTraining\img_y0.jpg", target_size= (500, 500))

a = img_to_array(a)
b = img_to_array(b)

model.evaluate(a ,b)
```

Для удобства, я написал модуль, вот его код

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np
import os
from Images.LoadImage import *

class LoadImage(object):
    """Helps you work with images"""
    def add_array_of_image(image_path = None,image_size = (256, 256), numpy_array = None, my_grayscale = False, my_colormode = 'rgb', my_interpolation = 'nearest', my_dataformat = None, my_dtype = None):
        """Adding single image into your array"""
        loaded_image = load_img(image_path, grayscale=my_grayscale, color_mode=my_colormode, target_size=image_size, interpolation = my_interpolation)
        array_image = img_to_array(loaded_image, data_format=my_dataformat, dtype=my_dtype)
        numpy_array.append(array_image)


    def rename_all_files_in(dir_name, files_new_name = "img", counter_start = 0, images_extension = ".png"):
        """Renames all files in folder that you specified"""
        tree = os.walk(dir_name)
        trees_list = []
        names_list = []
        for i in tree:
            trees_list.append(i)
        for i in trees_list[0][2]:
            names_list.append(i)
        for i in names_list:
            os.chdir(dir_name)
            os.rename(src = i, dst = files_new_name + str(counter_start) + images_extension)
            counter_start += 1 

    def upload_all_images_with_name_from(directory = "C:\\", files_common_name = "img", files_counter_start = 0, files_extension = ".png", array = None,image_sizes = (256, 256), my_grayscales = False, my_colormodes = 'rgb', my_interpolations = 'nearest', my_dataformats = None, my_dtypes = None):
        """Uploads all images from folder that you specified in your array"""
        tree = os.walk(directory)
        trees_list = []
        names_list = []
        tmp1 = len(names_list)
        for i in tree:
            trees_list.append(i)
        for i in trees_list[0][2]:
            names_list.append(i)
        for i in range((len(names_list) - 1)):
            LoadImage.add_array_of_image(image_path = directory+ '\\' +files_common_name+ str(files_counter_start)+files_extension, image_size = image_sizes, numpy_array = array, my_grayscale = my_grayscales, my_colormode = my_colormodes, my_interpolation = my_interpolations, my_dtype = my_dtypes)
            files_counter_start += 1

    def save_model_json(model, file_path = None, write_mode = 'w', write_buffering = None, write_encoding = None):
        """Saves your model into some file"""
        file = open(file_path, write_mode,buffering = write_buffering, encoding = write_encoding)
        model_json = model.to_json()
        file.write(model_json)
        file.close()
```

Это вроде можно починить, если заменить input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],) на input_shape=(500, 500, 3), но особо это не спасло, так как появилась ошибка

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (500, 500, 1) but got array with shape (500, 500, 3)
```

Я пробовал изменить форму:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
```

И вот что из этого вышло:

```
cannot reshape array of size 133500000 into shape (178,1,500)
```

А если перед последним слоем поставить Flatten() слой, то ошибка такая же, как и  в случае (X_train.shape[1],)
Он требует чтобы был только один канал цвета? Или чтобы изображения были чёрно-белыми?

Comment: Зачем писать самописные сомнительные модули если в Keras уже есть все необходимое? [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/829438/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5/829833#829833)

Comment: Если вы говорите о генераторах, то я о них знаю. Но проблема в том, что для того, чтобы обучить сеть на генераторах, придётся использовать fit_genetator(), который хорошо работает с классификацией, но не подходит под задачи регрессии. Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли ещё решения данной проблемы? И можно ли всё-таки прикрутить генераторы, чтобы они подходили под нужные задачи?