# Как подать картинки на вход обученной модели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Как правильно создать циклы?

Имеется в папке 20 картинок JPEG. Требуется их подгрузить с помощью функции `util.load.img` и после, эти же 20 картинок циклом обойти функцией `predict`.

Answer (score 3):

Правильнее будет создать 4х-мерный тензор изображений, которые вы хотите подать на вход обученной модели для предсказаний.

В Keras для удобного и эффективного чтения изображений существует класс - [keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

[Пример использования `ImageDataGenerator`](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

[ещё один пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829833/211923)

Comment: Отличная информация!!!