# Как решить проблему с запуском собственного датасета для обучения нейросети?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть директория в ней две папки с изображениями зимы и лета (по 185 изображений). Пробую запустить обучение, но возникает ошибка: expected flatten_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (). Я ведь передаю в input_shape данное значение и почему 4 dimensions?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import keras 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 
 
train_images = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images'
 
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
 
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
 
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. /255)
 
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_images,
  target_size = (48,48),
  batch_size = 37,
  class_mode = 'binary')
 
model.fit(np.array(train_images), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Сама ошибка.

```
C:\Users\Администратор>C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyth
on36-32\image_guess.py
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda insta
ll m2w64-toolchain`
C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c+
+ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandat
ory
  warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to exe
cute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Pyth
on implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warnin
g, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS fu
nctions.
Found 370 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\image_g
uess.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(np.array(train_images), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape ()
```

Comment: model.fit_generator(train_generator, ...). Сейчас вы пытаетесь обучить модель на датасете состоящем из одного экземпляра -  пути к данным, вместо самих картинок

Comment: [рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829833/211923)

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, но там, насколько я понял, изображения перемешаны в одной папке?

Comment: @MaxU У меня -> training_data -> winter/summer (две папки, где расположены соответствующие изображения).

Comment: Ну, так сделайте так, что-бы вытягивалось из обеих папок, поочередно, а еще лучше -  в случайном порядке. Обучать сначала на данных одного класса, а потом  на данных другого - не лучшая идея.

Comment: @passant Случайно не подскажите, как это реализовать? Я честно предполагал, что train generator и перемешивает данные.

Comment: @passant как в случае случайного вытягивания, программа будет ставить метки? Ведь нейросеть должна понять что это зима, а это лето.

Comment: @Алекс, в примере по ссылке данные так и организованы - каждый класс лежит в отдельной директории. А вообще работа с нейронными сетями предполагает наличие умения и желания копаться в документации и активный поиск информации в сети ;)

Comment: @MaxU все увидел. Нужно в модель передавать train_generator, а не train_images. Конечно, теперь возникла новая ошибка "unable allocate 999 .kB for an array with shape", но буду искать. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
train_images = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images'
 
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
 
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

# size of mini-data
batch_size = 32
# train data
train_data_size = N # общее число картинок в обучающей выборке

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_images,
    target_size=(48, 48),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_data_size // batch_size,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Но все оказалось проще, в модель нужно передавать train_generator, а не train_images.

Comment: @Алекс, я вам об этом в самом первом комментарии написал ;) Кстати, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)