# Как решить проблему с нехваткой оперативной памяти при обучении модели keras?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Не хватает оперативной памяти, снизил размер изображений до 36 х 36. Этот же размер передаю в `input_shape`.

Появляется ошибка, где сказано, что памяти не хватает, а в скобках (256 х 256).

От чего так?

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import keras 
import joblib
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_images = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images'

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(36, 36, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. /255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_images,
  batch_size = 4,
  class_mode = 'binary')

model.fit(np.array(train_generator), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Ошибка (cmd).

```
Found 336 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\image_g
uess.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(np.array(train_generator), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 116, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 222, in _get_batches_of_
transformed_samples
    batch_x = np.zeros((len(index_array),) + self.image_shape, dtype=self.dtype)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.00 MiB for an array with shape (4, 256, 256, 3
) and data type float32
```

Comment: уменьшайте кол-во слоев, количество данных в обучении. Можно конечно докупить памяти, или заказать сервер на каком то хостинге с кучей памяти на несколько часов (может быть сильно дешевле) но это такое.

Comment: @KoVadim хорошо, спасибо за информация. Т.е это нормально, что вместо (4, 36, 36, 3) в консоли (4, 256, 256, 3)?

Comment: возможно. я никогда не работал с этой системой

Comment: Я вам [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1226016/211923) уже показал как это делается

Comment: @MaxU Да, я помню. Дело в том, что пытаюсь решить ошибку float() argument must be a string or a number, not Image (если делаем target_size меньше, чем параметры изображения) и not 'jpegimagefile' (если target_size = параметрам изображения). Вот и решил, убрать target_size вообще и посмотреть, что получится. Удивило отличие input_shape в консоли от действительного.

Comment: Врядли вам смогут помочь без __воспроизводимого__ примера данных

Comment: @MaxU А здесь есть возможность добавить архив с данными? Там всего 336 изображений.

Comment: @Алекс, вы всегда можете выложить архив на какой-нибудь файлообменник и привести ссылку...

Comment: @MaxU Хорошо, спасибо, я лучше создам новый вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разрешить проблемы с памятью, данные нужно обрабатывать пакетами (по `batch_size` картинок за раз):

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

# size of mini-data
batch_size = 32
# train data
train_data_size = N # общее число картинок в обучающей выборке

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_images,
    target_size=(48, 48),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_data_size // batch_size,
    epochs=10)
```