# Как разбивается выборка для обучения RCNN?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, keras

Здраствуйте, помогите понять, пожалуйста.

Мнист взят только для описания ситуации:

> (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

Думаю многие видели эту строку, поажлуйста помогите понять как собрать аналог?
У меня дана выборка, два класса. Классификация в тексте, я создал словарь на всю выборку вида:
{name_file: num_class}

Как это всё состыковать, и как понять какие пропорции внутри? Я хочу рандом, без всяких наложений.

Далее у меня идёт такая конструкция в коде:

> x_train_split, x_val_split, y_train_split, y_val_split = **train_test_split**(x_train, y_train_cat, test_size=0.2)
>
> model.fit(x_train_split, y_train_split, batch_size=32, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_val_split, y_val_split))

Здесь я разбиваю вручную. Но в голове не проясняется. Как тут вообще понять в каких пропорциях разбивается **общая** выборка на **тестовую** и далее на **обучающую** с **валидационной**?

Я пролазил туториалки по тензорфлоу, по керасу, и по аугментациям зачем-то. У меня получилось в однмо варианте создать класс, в другом словарь. Но я не понимаю где и в каком месте далее это всё регулируется и при каких обстоятельствах считывается для сравнения результатов на всех этапах.. Ютуб уже закончился. Я даже класс могу в название файла записать, или разбить вручную по папкам. Взять чужой код с каггла и сделать рабочим, но это не даёт понимания.

**Upd:** Так, стоп. Я же могу применить **train_test_split** и в первом случае? а как будет выглядеть взаимодействие и код.. со словарём из названия файлов и класса? оно же не преобразуется в вектор нампи и класс? или да? о боже мой ..  %(

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Попробую ответить на то, что понял.

Команда:

```
x_train_split, x_val_split, y_train_split, y_val_split = \
    train_test_split(x_train, y_train_cat, test_size=0.2)
```

разбивает общую выборку на две части - обучающую 80% и валидационную 20%.

Дальше вы обучаете модель на обучающей выборке (80%) и проверяете качество модели на ваоидационной выборке (20%).

Я нигде не увидел в вашем коде никаких упоминаний о **тестовой** выборке.

---

Можно сделать немного по-другому:

разбиваем общую выборку на две части: 90% и 10% (тестовая выборка):

```
x_train_split, x_test_split, y_train_split, y_test_split = \
    train_test_split(x_train, y_train_cat, test_size=0.1)
```

При обучении модели можно воспользоваться параметром:

> **validation_split**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this
> fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate
> the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch.
> The validation data is selected from the last samples in the `x` and `y`
> data provided, before shuffling. This argument is not supported when `x`
> is a dataset, generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` instance.

```
model.fit(x_train_split, y_train_split, batch_size=32, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2)
```

т.е. keras откусит 20% от обучающей выборки `x_train_split` и будет использовать эту часть для валидации модели.

В самом конце вы можете протестировать модель на тестовой выборке, данные из которой модель не видела ни при обучении ни при валидации.

Comment: > (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
так, вот первое деление, тут из 70 000 пишут что откусывается 10 000 на тестовую
а вот тут:
> x_train_split, x_test_split, y_train_split, y_test_split = \
    train_test_split(x_train, y_train_cat, test_size=0.1)
я уже тренировочную выборку руками поделил, тут я понимаю. меня интересует как я в первую фазу могу контролировать деление

Comment: что такое первая фаза?

Comment: я не понимаю именно тот момент, как из своего словаря, а не мниста, мне зарандомить первичное деление О_о

Comment: вы можете изъясняться понятнее?

Comment: я стараюсь).. я поинмаю что я на чём-то простом замкнулся %(
ну, изначально mnist.load_data() наполняет вот эти кортежи нампай (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) 
как мне подменить mnist.load_data() своим наполнителем, с возможностью рандома при каждой инициации, ведь если я создал свой словарь, в нём будет хранится индекс и значение. в моём словаре индекс это имя файла, а значение - его класс. Имя файла не есть вектор для наполнения..

Comment: Все подмодули в `tf.keras.datasets` (такие как `mnist.load_data()`) построены на известных и публично доступных датасетах - в них ничего поменять или подставить нельзя. Опишите подробнее что у вас за данные (не словарь, который вы создали, а изначальные данные), далее опишите что вы понимаете под "с возможностью рандома при каждой инициации"?

Comment: у меня кошки собаки, и к каждой картинке идёт одноимённый текстовый файл, в котором указан класс 1 - кшока, 2 - собака. я добился 99,17 % на мнисте, хочу на кошках и собаках приблизится, а поделить их по человечески не знаю как. Ведь в подмодулях кероса всё поделено по человечески. Мне и не нужно в них лезть. я хочу сосавить свою таблицу, с двумя столбцами: 1 - вектор, 2 - класс. Чтобы она была в состоянии рандомится по аналогии с train_test_split - тут есть такая опция.

Comment: Так бы сразу и сказали) В keras уже есть [все необходимое для этого](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) Все что вам нужно сделать - это разложить все картинки по двум директориям (`cat`, `dog`) и удалить текстовые файлы с лейблами. [Пример использования...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/829833/211923)

Comment: ооо.. я был на этой странице. Так что неужели вручную раскладывать только? а если у меня там ещё рамки будут с локализацией.. но на этот случай я уже своим скриптом навырезал, так что мне достаточно разложить по папкам.. спасибо, пойду в этом направлении провертяь

Comment: зачем вручную? такие вещи на том же Python за 10-15 минут делаются

Comment: так у меня скрипт готов, это и есть вручную, я имел ввиду не телом самой программы, которая будет сеть тренировать).. спасибо что напомнили про эту ссылку.. я её с самого начала видел, и забыл совсем..

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy

в туториале по тензорфлоу описано почти всё, что меня интересовало) спасибо за внимание

Загрузите массивы NumPy с помощью tf.data.Dataset

Предполагая, что у вас есть массив примеров и соответствующий массив меток, передайте два массива в виде кортежа в **tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices** чтобы создать **tf.data.Dataset**

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_examples, train_labels))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_examples, test_labels))
```

Перемешайте и пакетируйте наборы данных

````
BATCH_SIZE = 64 
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 100 
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE) 
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)```
````